# Error running Gulp on SASS task

Tags: ruby, gulp

I am trying to install and try out [zurb's foundation for apps](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-apps). I have installed NPM, Ruby, Sass, Bundler. When I run `gulp` from the command-line, I receive the following error:

```
[12:36:56] gulp-ruby-sass: stderr: C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundle
r-1.7.6/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize': Could not find sas
s-3.4.7 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/sp
ec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/sp
ec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/de
finition.rb:132:in `specs'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/de
finition.rb:177:in `specs_for'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/de
finition.rb:166:in `requested_specs'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/en
vironment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/ru
ntime.rb:13:in `setup'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler.rb
:121:in `setup'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/se
tup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55
:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55
:in `require'
[12:36:56] Finished 'sass' after 2.49 s
```

I do not understand what I did wrong or what I'm missing. I'm not a Ruby guy. If someone could please tell me what I'm doing wrong, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: How have you installed ruby and sass?

Comment: @Aperçu Yes. I have ran ruby and sass. I have confirmed this by running `ruby -v` from the command-line. This prints out "ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x64-mingw32]". When I type `sass -v` from the command-line, I see "Sass 3.4.8 (Selective Steve)"

Comment: By looking at source code of [gulpfile.js](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-apps/blob/master/gulpfile.js) you can see that there are `sass` and `node-sass` tasks. Both do exactly the same thing but the second one uses `node-sass` js lib instead of ruby's `sass`. I'd suggest trying running `gulp node-sass` to see how it goes.

Comment: Have you tried ````bundler update````